# getting error with getint(0) in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

In this code i have an error reading columns that my data base reader get from a query.
The error is in the line :

```
DbCom.CommandText = System.String.Format("INSERT into Cortex(IdDA,Vlsd) values({0},'yes')",DbReader.GetInt16(0));
```

they saied that no data exist in ligne or colomn, but it really exist.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=savior"))
            {
                DbConnection.Open();
                OdbcCommand DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
                DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT IDA FROM Dchas";
                try
                {
                    DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    int fCount = DbReader.FieldCount;
                    if (fCount > 0)
                    {
                        do
                        {

                            using (OdbcConnection DbConnect = new OdbcConnection("DSN=savior"))
                            {
                                DbConnect.Open();
                                OdbcCommand DbCom = DbConnect.CreateCommand();
                                DbCom.CommandText = System.String.Format("INSERT into Cortex(IdDA,Vlsd) values({0},'yes')",DbReader.GetInt16(0));

                                try
                                {
                                    DbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                                catch (OdbcException ex)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Executing the query2 failed.");
                                    Console.WriteLine("The OdbcCommand returned the following message");
                                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                                    return;
                                }
                            }

                        } while (DbReader.Read());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Query affected row(s)");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (OdbcException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Executing the query1 failed.");
                    Console.WriteLine("The OdbcCommand returned the following message");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are entering your `do..while loop` without a call to `DBReader.Read` before trying to access the DBReader data.

The best fix is to change the loop to

```
while(DBReader.Read())
{
    .....

}
```

this will avoid to enter the loop if the Reader query doesn't return any records

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can save a lot of code (and a lot of potential errors like that one) if you use the features the database already supplies. Copying records from one table to the next is something you should let the database worry about:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var connection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=savior"))
        {
            const string Sql = "INSERT INTO Cortex( IdDA, Vlsd ) SELECT IDA, 'yes' FROM Dchas";

            connection.Open();

            using(var command = new OdbcCommand(Sql))
            {
                int numberOfRecords = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Copied {0} rows.", numberOfRecords);
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you have write here ?

Comment: You pull data from the database and then insert it again one by one. That's inefficient. You can instruct the database to just copy it inside the database without the need to push it over the network to your computer where you push it back one by one to the database. The 6 lines above will do the same your 20 lines do.

Comment: yes, i agree, but in my real code, I do have so mush operations to apply to each data, and more, the program have from time to an other problem with some data, I have to know it and catch the error name and .... for every one alone.